# Protege 5.0.0 Classify button

Tags: protege

I am following a tutorial of Pizza Ontology and it says I need to select Classify button under Reasoner tab. But the version I am using, i.e. Protégé 5.0.0-beta-23, there is no such button under the Reasoner tab.

Do you know here I can find this function?

Answer (score 7):

The tutorial is out of date on the instructions.

To reason on Protege 5, use the Reasoner menu, click on one of the available reasoners at the bottom of the menu (e.g., HermiT), then go again in the reasoner menu and select `Start reasoner`.

Answer (score 2):

According to the vocabulary in [section 4.9](http://mowl-power.cs.man.ac.uk/protegeowltutorial/resources/ProtegeOWLTutorialP4_v1_3.pdf)

> Reasoners are sometimes called classifiers. Classification, however, is not the only inference service provided by reasoners ...

So, the button `Classify...` is simply a way to trigger or invoke the reasoner in order to

> test whether or not one class is a subclass of another class or check
>   for inconsistencies.

To invoke the reasoner in Protégé 5, you can follow the instructions of [Ignazio's post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35853599/5657159) and you will see the output is quite similar to the description in the tutorial that is: `ProbeInconsistentTopping` turns to be red.